# Carousel items are not showing on mobile view

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

i'm using boostrap Carousel i put few items on image in laptop view it's looking perfect but on mobile view items are not showing
here is laptop view
[image]

here is the mobile view
[image]

```
        <section class="hero-wrap">
        <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img src="images/bg_1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                        <div class="overlay"></div>
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row  slider-text ">
                                <div class="col-md-10 ftco-animate text-center">
                                    <br><br>
                                    <div class="icon">
                                        <span class="flaticon-lotus"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <h1>Spa &amp; Beauty Center</h1>
                                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                        <div class="col-md-7 mb-3">
                                            <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia
                                                and
                                                Consonantia,
                                                there live the blind texts.</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <p>
                                        <a href="pricing.php" class="btn btn-primary p-3 px-5 py-4 mr-md-2">Prices</a>
                                        <a href="booking.php"
                                            class="btn btn-outline-primary p-3 px-5 py-4 ml-md-2">Booking</a>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="images/bg_2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                        <div class="overlay"></div>
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row slider-text">
                                <div class="col-md-10 ftco-animate text-center">
                                    <div class="icon">
                                        <span class="flaticon-lotus"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <h1>Spa &amp; Beauty Center</h1>
                                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                        <div class="col-md-7 mb-3">
                                            <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia
                                                and
                                                Consonantia,
                                                there live the blind texts.</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <p>
                                        <a href="pricing.php" class="btn btn-primary p-3 px-5 py-4 mr-md-2">Prices</a>
                                        <a href="booking.php"
                                            class="btn btn-outline-primary p-3 px-5 py-4 ml-md-2">Booking</a>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="images/bg_3.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                        <div class="overlay"></div>
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row slider-text">
                                <div class="col-md-10 ftco-animate text-center">
                                    <div class="icon">
                                        <span class="flaticon-lotus"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <h1>Spa &amp; Beauty Center</h1>
                                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                        <div class="col-md-7 mb-3">
                                            <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia
                                                and
                                                Consonantia,
                                                there live the blind texts.</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <p>
                                        <a href="pricing.php" class="btn btn-primary p-3 px-5 py-4 mr-md-2">Prices</a>
                                        <a href="booking.php"
                                            class="btn btn-outline-primary p-3 px-5 py-4 ml-md-2">Booking</a>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
    </section>

And css code is

.carousel-item {
height: 100vh;
min-height: 300px;
background: no-repeat scroll center scroll;
\--webkit-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}

    .carousel-item::before {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        background: #000;
        opacity: 0.1;
    }
    .carousel-caption{
        bottom:75px;
        padding-left:200px;
        padding-right:50px;
    }
    @media (max-width: 600px) {
        .carousel-item {
            height: 0;
        min-height: 270px;
        }
        
    }
```

i'm using boostrap Carousel i put few items on image in laptop view it's looking perfect but on mobile view items are not showing
here is laptop view
[image]

here is the mobile view
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is because Bootstrap displays .d-none class as none (with !important). If you want to overwright Bootstrap and show it in small screens use inline css (in HTML). You will also then need to add style accordingly for small screens (decrease size of buttons..)

```css
.carousel-item {
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 300px;
    background: no-repeat scroll center scroll;
    /* --webkit-background-size: cover; */
    background-size: cover;
    }
    
        .carousel-item::before {
            content: "";
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            background: #000;
            opacity: 0.1;
        }
        .carousel-caption{
            bottom:75px;
            padding-left:200px;
            padding-right:50px;
        }
        @media (max-width: 600px) {
            .carousel-item {
                height: 0;
            min-height: 270px;
            }
                      .carousel-caption{
            min-width: 200px !important;
            font-size: 10px;
            left: -20% !important;
          }

          .carousel-caption .container{
            min-width: 100px !important;
            padding: 0 !important;

          }

          .carousel-caption h1{
            font-size: 15px;
          }

          .carousel-caption p a.btn{
            font-size: 2vw;
            padding: 5px !important;
          }
            
        }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <section class="hero-wrap">
        <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block" style="display:flex !important;">
                        <div class="overlay"></div>
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row  slider-text ">
                                <div class="col-md-10 ftco-animate text-center">
                                    <br><br>
                                    <div class="icon">
                                        <span class="flaticon-lotus"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <h1>Spa &amp; Beauty Center</h1>
                                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                        <div class="col-md-7 mb-3">
                                            <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia
                                                and
                                                Consonantia,
                                                there live the blind texts.</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <p>
                                        <a href="pricing.php" class="btn btn-primary p-3 px-5 py-4 mr-md-2">Prices</a>
                                        <a href="booking.php"
                                            class="btn btn-outline-primary p-3 px-5 py-4 ml-md-2">Booking</a>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block" style="display:flex !important;">
                        <div class="overlay"></div>
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row slider-text">
                                <div class="col-md-10 ftco-animate text-center">
                                    <div class="icon">
                                        <span class="flaticon-lotus"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <h1>Spa &amp; Beauty Center</h1>
                                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                        <div class="col-md-7 mb-3">
                                            <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia
                                                and
                                                Consonantia,
                                                there live the blind texts.</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <p>
                                        <a href="pricing.php" class="btn btn-primary p-3 px-5 py-4 mr-md-2">Prices</a>
                                        <a href="booking.php"
                                            class="btn btn-outline-primary p-3 px-5 py-4 ml-md-2">Booking</a>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block" style="display:flex !important;">
                        <div class="overlay"></div>
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row slider-text">
                                <div class="col-md-10 ftco-animate text-center">
                                    <div class="icon">
                                        <span class="flaticon-lotus"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <h1>Spa &amp; Beauty Center</h1>
                                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                        <div class="col-md-7 mb-3">
                                            <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia
                                                and
                                                Consonantia,
                                                there live the blind texts.</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <p>
                                        <a href="pricing.php" class="btn btn-primary p-3 px-5 py-4 mr-md-2">Prices</a>
                                        <a href="booking.php"
                                            class="btn btn-outline-primary p-3 px-5 py-4 ml-md-2">Booking</a>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
    </section>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+sLIOodYLS7CIrQpBjl+C7nPvqq+FbNUBDunl/OZv93DB7Ln/533i8e/mZXLi/P+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: it's not looking good on mobile view can you please help me and make it same as displaying on laptop view

Comment: I just edited the code and made some minimal adjustments hope that helps. You can still adjust the styling if you want.

Comment: sir the content which is displaying on the laptop view is not looking on mobile can you plz modify it and make similar like it is showing in laptop view please check the screenshot which is attach in this post

Comment: It is actualy just check the code snippet. You Can also check on your code editor with devtools